# How parameter by reference/value works in C#

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have this sample code:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        public static void Foo(MyClass v)
        {
            v.Value = 2;
            v = new MyClass();
            v.Value = 3;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var m = new MyClass();
            m.Value = 1;
            Foo(m);
            Console.Write(m.Value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I would like to understand why the output is 2 and not 3, could you please give me some clear explanation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will go through with you, step by step via the debugger and we will see what it is 2.

[image: Step1]

We see that we entered into Foo and we passed an instance of MyClass by reference `v` (class instances in C# are passed by reference by default)

In memory, we would see something like this:

```
v = 0x01; //0x01 - is a simple representation of a pointer that we passed
v.Value = 1;
```

next, we step over and we see that we change the value Value in our reference.
[image: step 2]

```
v = 0x01;
v.Value = 2; // our new value
```

and then we assign `new` to our `v` so in memory we have

```
v* = 0x01 // this is our "old" object
v*.Value = 2;
v = 0x02 // this is our "new" object
v.Value = 3;
```

as you can see we have 2 objects in the memory! The new one `v` and the old one marked with a start `v*`

when we exit the method, we didn't replace the content of the memory address `0x01` but created a local copy of `v` for the scope of the functions, and we created a new object under the memory address `0x02` which is not referenced in our Main method.

[image: step3]

Our main method is using instance from address `0x01` not new `0x02` we created in Foo method!

To make sure we pass the right object out, we need to tell C# that we want to either "edit" output using `ref` or we want to "overwrite" output using `out`.

Under the hood, they are implemented the same way!

Instead of passing `0x01` to our Foo method, we pass `0x03`! which has a pointer to our class under `0x01`. So when we assign `v = new MyClass()` when we use `ref` or `out`, we, in reality, modify the value of `0x03` which is then extracted and "replaced" in our Main method to contain the proper value!

Comment: "we passed v by reference" - I guess `v` is more a reference than an instance and this is passed by value (this is why the question makes sense), but the instance of the class referenced by `v` is passed by reference (namely by `v`) as you correctly concluded in the parentheses

Comment: @E.Shcherbo you are right. `v` is a reference - which is a value that points to a class instance, but sees how your sentence is complicated! It took me a good minute to understand it!

Comment: I agree and sorry I wasn't trying to say that you wrote something wrong, I just wrote the conclusion which once helped me to completely understand passing by reference and value, so probably it would be also useful for someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a reference to the method, that reference is copied into another variable on the stack. These two variables (references) might still reference the same object, but the variables themselves are different. It's the same as this:

```
var m = new MyClass();
m.Value = 1;
var s = m;
s.Value = 2; // m.Value is also 2
s = new MyClass();
s.Value = 3; // m.Value is still 2
```

You wouldn't expect to have `m.Value` equals to `3` here, because you had two different variables which referenced the same object on the heap, but then you changed `s` so that it references a brand new object. The same happens when you pass a reference to the method, it's just copied into another variable.

**The main idea** you can get from this is that **instances** of classes are passed **by reference** by default (because you actually pass reference), but **the references** themselves are passed **by value**, which means that they are copied into another variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call `Foo(m)`, `v` and `m` are separate references to the same object.

Reassigning to `v` does not reassign to `m`.

Contrast this with the below:

```
public static void Foo(ref MyClass v)
{
    v.Value = 2;
    v = new MyClass();
    v.Value = 3;
}
```

Through the use of `ref`, if you now call `Foo(m)`, `v` and `m` become the *same reference* to the same object, so reassigning to `v` also reassigns to `m`: making this output 3:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var m = new MyClass();
    m.Value = 1;
    Foo(m);
    Console.Write(m.Value);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initializing `v` object inside `Foo` function creates a new `MyClass` instance however it's reference is not set to `m` object inside `Main` function. Because reference of object is passed by value.

If you want it to be referenced inside `Foo` you should use `ref` like this;

`public static void Foo(ref MyClass v)`

and call it like this;

`Foo(ref m)`

You can also use `out` instead of `ref` if parameter passed **must** be initizalied by the method.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment that `v = new MyClass();` is called, inside Foo, the reference stops pointing to the object that was passed, instead it now points to the new object that was created.

This does not effect the caller, as the new object is not created at the memory that was allocated for the old one, rather the variable v now points to the new object, instead of the object that it used to point to.

That is why Foo effects the value to be 2, its the original object, but after the reassignment of v, the original object is not effected

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        public static void Foo(MyClass v)
        {
            v.Value = 2;
            v = new MyClass(); // this will make v point to an other object
            v.Value = 3;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var m = new MyClass();
            m.Value = 1;
            Foo(m);
            Console.Write(m.Value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```