# Return Type from Task<Type> in ASP.NET CORE Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a method in my

***BaseController***

```
public async Task<BaseModel> PopulateBaseModelAsync(BaseModel m)
{
    m.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    m.CreatedById = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    m.CreatedByUsername = User.Identity.Name;
    return m;
}
```

It's forced to be an `async Task` because of the `_userManager.GetUserAsync` method.

In a derived controller I want to pass in an `BaseModel` and have those three properties populated e.g.

***DerivedController***

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CategoriesCreateAsync(BookingCategory bc)
{
    if(bc != null)
    {
        bc = (BookingCategory)PopulateBaseModelAsync(bc);
        _context.BookingCategories.Add(bc);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(CategoriesIndex));
}
```

I originally wanted `PopulateBaseModel(BaseModel)` to just return a new BaseModel e.g. below, but because of the forced `async` method I'm not sure how to achieve this.

#### Original aim

***BaseController***

```
    public BaseModel PopulateBaseModel(BaseModel m)
    {
        m.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        m.CreatedById = _userManager.GetUser(User); // Must use async :(
        m.CreatedByUsername = User.Identity.Name;
        return m;
    }
```

***DerivedController***

```
    public IActionResult CategoriesCreate(BookingCategory bc)
    {
        if(bc != null)
        {
            bc = (BookingCategory)PopulateBaseModel(bc);
            _context.BookingCategories.Add(bc);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(CategoriesIndex));
    }
```

My main issue is I don't really understand how `Task` works - the method

```
public async Task<BaseModel> PopulateBaseModelAsync(BaseModel m)
```

allows me to return `BaseModel` but it won't compile because it can't `convert Task<BaseModel> to BookingCategory`

Comment: "_I originally wanted `PopulateBaseModel(IBaseModel)` to just return a new `IBaseModel`_" Why is that exactly? The effect of using `async` is that it grows through the call stack.

Comment: By the way, if you need `PopulateBaseModelAsync` to return a specific type, you could make it generic: `Task<TBaseModel> PopulateBaseModelAsync<TBaseModel>(TBaseModel m) where TBaseModel : IBaseModel`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I tried using `ref` with the `IBaseModel` to alter the properties directly but again because of the `async` usage it denied me - I'm not sure how `Task` works, I've never been able to get my head round what it does.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, subbed the `Interface` for a solid `Type` but obviously I still have my  `can't convert Task<T> to T` issue

Comment: After looking at your code again, you don't need the generic method because you don't need to reassign to `bc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your just missing an `await`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CategoriesCreateAsync(BookingCategory bc)
{
    if(bc != null)
    {
        await PopulateBaseModelAsync(bc);
        _context.BookingCategories.Add(bc);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(CategoriesIndex));
}
```

Because `PopulateBaseModelAsync` returns a `Task<IBaseModel>` you need to await it's completion.

Here the `Task` represents an I/O operation, who's result isn't immediately available.

Without awaiting the `Task`, your method would continue before the result is obtained.

No need to re-assign to `bc` either, because `PopulateBaseModelAsync` is modifying the instance it references.

Comment: Ahhh OK so this is new knowledge for me - I had no idea that the parameter passed to the Async method would be a `ref` type - wow! That makes things a lot simpler. I tend to avoid `Task` where possible, usually ending up in convoluted code - but that sheds new light on it for me.

Comment: The times I've tried to use it I've figured that async needs to wait for completion, but think I've always been trying to return a type... several times I've come across this issue, and never had anyone explain it in one line like that. THANKS!!!

Comment: Your getting mixed up with `ref`. In .NET, when you pass a reference type (such as `IBaseModel`) to a method, you are creating _another reference to the same object_ irrespective as to whether `ref` is used. Using `async` does not change that either. When you use `ref`, the difference is you are passing the reference as well as the object. This might make it clearer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65028524/8126362